# sweetalert evitar que se ponga automaticamente al cargar pagina

Tags: javascript, html, css, sweetalert2

Buen dia, estoy intentando usar sweetalert, se supone que al dar click en un boton deberia aparecerme la alerta pero esto no ocurre de hecho, al iniciar se pone automaticamente cada que cargo la pagina
lo que yo quiero lograr es que solo al dar click al boton aparezca la alerta, no cada que la pagina se refresque

```js
Swal.fire(
   'Ha guardado un registro!',   
   'success'
 )
```

```css
 .show-example-btn {
  font-family: "Open Sans", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
}
```

```html
<script src="sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sweetalert2.min.css">
<div class="showcase sweet">
      <button
        class="show-example-btn"
        aria-label="Show SweetAlert2 success message"
        onclick="executeExample('sweetAlert')">
        Guardar
      </button>
      <pre data-example-id="sweetAlert"></pre>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes poner a `Swal.fire()` dentro de una función, por ejemplo:

```
function successAlert() {
    Swal.fire(
   'Ha guardado un registro!',   
   'success'
 )
}
```

Y llamar a esta función al hacer click en un botón:

```
<button onclick="successAlert()"></button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he intentado y aun no funciona, el boton no hace nada, solo se queda ahi sin hacer nada:(

Comment: Cuidado en el orden en el que importas los scripts en el html, primero debe ir los scripts de sweetaler2 y por debajo de este tu script donde está definienda la función.

Comment: oh, muchas gracias, no sabia que eso afectaba, mil gracias !!